# Parsing Dynamic JSON Generated From Website (CoovaChilli) And Display It Into Javascript Webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jsonp

i really need your help to help me solving my problem. I setup a captive portal using CoovaChilli, and want to show the usage feedback provided by Coova JSON Interface that can be accessed via url like this **http://login.domain.com:3990/json/status** from the internal network where the CoovaChilli listen on. If you already logged in into the captive portal and then if you access that url you will see data formated like this in your browser:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "clientState": 1,
    "redir": {
        "originalURL": "http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204",
        "redirectionURL": "",
        "logoutURL": "http://10.1.0.1:3990/logoff",
        "ipAddress": "10.1.0.6",
        "macAddress": "AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF"
    },
    "session": {
        "sessionId": "5108c39600000003",
        "userName": "user@ri",
        "startTime": 1359529249,
        "sessionTimeout": 0,
        "idleTimeout": 900
    },
    "accounting": {
        "sessionTime": 867,
        "idleTime": 0,
        "inputOctets": 1428643,
        "outputOctets": 391752,
        "inputGigawords": 0,
        "outputGigawords": 0,
        "viewPoint": "client"
    }
}
```

My question is, what should i do if **want to parsing that data into a webpage using **Javascript**** so i can see that data formatted more nicely (html formatted). For example i can access it via url using same domain like this http://login.domain.com/status/status.html rather than unformatted data in the previous url ?

Please note : i want use javascript to parsing because the data is different by the user who logged in into that CoovaChilli, different user have different data, only user who logged in and accessing that url can see only their own statistic, so i think the best practice is use a client side language to parsing that data.

Any of your help is very appreciated. Thank you before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

This link may help you http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JSON Object Creation in JavaScript</h2>

<p>
Name: <span id="jname"></span><br>  
Age: <span id="jage"></span><br> 
Address: <span id="jstreet"></span><br> 
Phone: <span id="jphone"></span><br> 
</p>  

<script>
var JSONObject = {
  "name":"John Johnson",
  "street":"Oslo West 16", 
  "age":33,
  "phone":"555 1234567"};
document.getElementById("jname").innerHTML=JSONObject.name  
document.getElementById("jage").innerHTML=JSONObject.age  
document.getElementById("jstreet").innerHTML=JSONObject.street  
document.getElementById("jphone").innerHTML=JSONObject.phone  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit

If you want to remove var json you can use ajax or jquery
eg:

```
 $.getJSON("your url",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("div").append(field + " ");
    });
  });
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_getjson.asp

Comment: what me do if want change the var JSONObject data source from direct declared in the script like your answer into from webpage in my question (http://login.domain.com:3990/json/status) ? that is the problem.. i really don't know how to and can't find the answer on google.

Comment: and the implementation if me use the second script, what should i do if want to combine it with the first script ? (insert variable data from the webpage with getJSON) me confuse with the JSON structure on my question with the example structure on w3school because it is different. If you can please show me just one example for understand how to parsing that data structure in my question. Me still zero knowledge about JSON parsing, but really want to know it more.. ty before.

Comment: nope, only understand little bit but me quick learning if see the example. From it i can understand how something work. For my question above, now only need how to combine the data from the webpage using getJSON or something different so it can be inserted into the variable and then can be printed into html formatted ?

Comment: the variable 'result' contains the json object returned from the server. Just alert it.. You will understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $.getJSON("http://10.1.0.1:3990/json/status?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  </script>
```